# How i can restrict the color of a NSColorWell

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I need to give my user the option to choose a color from a set of 12 colors, my ideia is to use the NSColorWell, but i cannot find the way to restrict the options in the color picker to only the 12 collars.

Comment: Be creative like using a drop-down menu with color images as menu items.  NSColorWell is a trouble maker.  You are better of not using it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, its lead me in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future googlers, subclass the NSPopUpButton and:

```
private var colors: [NSColor]?

func setColors(_ colors: [NSColor]) {
    self.colors = colors
    self.reloadMenu()
}

private func reloadMenu(){

    guard let colorsArray = colors else { return }

    var image: NSImage

    for index in 0..<itemArray.count {

        image = NSImage(size: NSSize(width: 100, height: 13))
        image.lockFocus()
        let color = colorsArray[index]
        color.setFill()
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 13))
        path.fill()
        image.unlockFocus()

        itemArray[index].image = image
    }
    self.synchronizeTitleAndSelectedItem()
    self.display()
}
```